# I want to display author gravatar on posts. How to do this?

Tags: gravatar

I just want to add author gravatar near the name of the author. I know that I have to add something in the single.php file, but what to add? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're in the Loop:

`echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta('ID') );`

Comment: It worked just fine!

Answer (score 3):

Plenty of info on [WP Codex on Gravatar's](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Gravatars).

use: `get_avatar( "id of author" );`